# Convert Internal Storage to Phone Storage

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, internal-storage, internal-sd

I have a Wiko Darkmoon running 4.2.2 (Wiko hasn't upgraded to 4.4 yet). The phone is advertised as having 4gb storage, which breaks down as

1. Cache: ~123MB, /cache
2. Internal: ~1008MB, /data
3. Protect:~9MB, /protect_s
4. Sdcard2: ~1749MB, /mnt/sdcard2
5. System:: ~690MB. /system

Total: ~3579MB ~ 3.5GB.

(info retrieved using FreeSpace https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.krikun.freespace).

On top of this I have mounted a 32GB SD card (/storage/sdcard0). My options are to by default use the external sd card. Unfortunately the /data is full and it basically prevents me to install more programs.

Also, the Sdcard2 thingy is supposed to be internal and it's completely free.

My question is, can I convert Sdcard2 to mount with /data? Having +1GB in /data would alleviate my storage constraints a lot.

I googled and searched here and it seems this is not a common issue. Most of the things I've read are about mounting everything in the external SD card, which is not the same I want to do: I want to reuse the internal 1.7GB by joining it to Internal (/data) partition.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not saying this for sure ! But as far as i had checked the partitioning topics and also in my own experience i'd dived into actions about that .

i do not recommend you delete a partition completely , Because first of all it may cause an error so you can safely reduce it's size to very low & keeping that tiny space for the system presentations and checks (android checks much much things that we can't even guess those are counted as an important thing for the system to run) . 
I'm not a pro at all Just hoped to be usefull :)

Comment: This is not a good idea. Android M and on have a system to treat an SD card as part of the internal storage, which is far preferred to this, which may softbrick or even hardbrick the device.